# Looking for high (temporal) frequency wind data

Tags: weather

I'm looking for data sources providing high temporal frequency wind data. Once per minute would be preferred. The [TCOONS dataset](http://www.cbi.tamucc.edu/TCOON/) is a great example. I identified this after speaking with a local National Weather Service office, who directed me to it.

Is there any nationwide listing of such datasets? Most of the wind data available appear to be daily or 20 minute averages......

Comment: Are you familiar with http://mesowest.utah.edu/ ? Most of these stations update only every 20 minutes (as you note), but some do update more frequently. Another option is http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/overview.asp but the data may be less accurate.

Comment: mesowest looks great-- thank you. I've also found some great one minute and five minute data from NOAA here: https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/land-based-station-data/land-based-datasets/automated-surface-observing-system-asos

Comment: @BarryCarter you should post your comment as an answer

Comment: I honestly don't think it's good enough to be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Met Office in te UK - http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/datapoint 
They collect and model peta bytes of global data. Not sure if they have your  particular dataset but are the nr 1 weather experts globally. 
In the UK there is one centralised organisation (funded by tax money),  unlike several ones in the US. However their data is used globally by many.